# npm WARN eslint-plugin-vue@6.2.2 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed

Tags: npm, eslint, eslint-plugin-vue

Why do I get this error message while I already have a version of `eslint` higher than `5.0.0` in my Laravel project ?

```
$ npm install
npm WARN eslint-plugin-vue@6.2.2 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

```
$ eslint -v
v7.9.0
```

Comment: Because that doesn't say "higher than 5.0.0", it says "5.x.y or 6.x.y". Have you actually had a problem running the linting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read what the caret "^" does in semantic version syntax.
Generally speaking, the caret means:
^version “Compatible with version”, will update you to all future minor/patch versions, without incrementing the major version. ^2.3.4 will use releases from 2.3.4 to <3.0.0.

Since you have version 7.9.0, that is neither compatible with 6 nor with 5, so it's normal that it gives you an error.